# HTML parsing with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, loops

I am trying to iterate over a bunch of html tags but need a little guidance. How would I iterate through a bunch of table rows with Beautiful Soup, and output the link text?

HTML:

```
<div id="thisDiv">
    <table class="thisTable">
        <tr>
            <td><a href="blablabl">BLABLABLA1</a></td><td><a href="blablabla2">BLABLABLA2</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="blablab3">BLABLABLA3</a></td><td><a href="blablabla4">BLABLABLA4</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="blablab5">BLABLABLA5</a></td><td><a href="blablabla6">BLABLABLA6</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to iterate through the rows. Just locate the table and search for all the anchors it contains:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(doc)
table = soup.find('table', {'class':'thisTable'}) 
for a in table.findAll('a'):
    print a.text
```

Comment: Thanks.  If I have multiple tables with class thisTable, how do I specify the one that is a child of #thisDiv?

Comment: @KingKongFrog use `div = soup.find('div', {'id':'thisDiv'})` and if it only contains one table, you can search the div itself for anchors instead. Otherwise locate the table within the div with `table = div.find(...)`.